# a "probability density function" that isn't normalized

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions

Let me describe a simple calculation that I wish to generalize. Suppose I roll $n$ dice. The probability of at least one six is
$$
P(\text{at least one six}) = 1- P(\text{no sixes}) = 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n [1-P(\text{a six})]
$$

Now suppose I sample $n$ numbers that I denote $x_n$, one from each of $n$ different pdfs that I denote with $p_n(x)$. The probability that one of the numbers I sample is between $z$ and $z+\Delta z$ is
$$
\begin{align*}
P(\text{at least one $x$ beteen $z$ and $z+\Delta z$}) &=  1 - P(\text{not one $x$ beteen $z$ and $z+\Delta z$}) \\
&= 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n [1-P(\text{$x_i$ beteen $z$ and $z+\Delta z$})]\\
&= 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n [1-p_i(z)\Delta z)]\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(z)\Delta z + \mathcal{O}(\Delta z^2) + \cdots\\
\end{align*}
$$
Now I take the limit $\Delta z \to 0$ and calculate a "density function"
$$
\begin{align*}
p(\text{at least one $x=z$}) &\equiv \lim{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{P(\text{at least one $x$ beteen $z$ and $z+\Delta z$})}{\Delta z}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n p_i(z)
\end{align*}
$$

This object is a density function - it's the sum of density functions - but it isn't itself a pdf, e.g.
$$
\int p(\text{at least one $x=z$}) dz = n \neq 1
$$
but it will satsify
$$
p(\text{at least one $x=z$}) dz + p(\text{not one $x=z$}) dz = 1
$$

What's the name for this kind of "probability" function? Do they have well-defined properties? Is it wise to introduce them or will they use lead to problems?

Comment: It has some applications -- see e.g. Section 5.6 of [DL01](http://luc.devroye.org/webbooktable.html).

Comment: thanks, that section is describing density estimates that turn out to have the wrong normalization. i don't think that's what i'm describing.